# Mongoose parser error while connecting with mongoDB atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

while trying to connect with my mongoDB atlas using mongoose connect method in node js I'm getting below mentioned parser error, I've checked my DB credentials and there are no special characters (:, /, ?, #, [], @) present in it.

Error:

```
MongoParseError: URI malformed, cannot be parsed
```

Code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const DB = process.env.DB.replace('<password>', process.env.DB_PASSWORD);
mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then((con) => {
    console.log(con.connections);
    console.log('DB connection successful!');
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried to log the `DB` to make sure? and which version of mongoose are you using?

Comment: Thanks Mostafa for your comment. I've logged the DB string and its showing the correct one only, which is also connecting correctly in mongoDB compass. mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.c1kshdj.mongodb.net/natours?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Comment: I'm using mongoose 5

Comment: Post upgrading the mongoose to version 6, my issue got resolved.